# Is there a special syntax for suspending a coroutine until a condition is met?

Tags: python, coroutine

I need to suspend a coroutine until a condition is met. Currently, I have:

```
class Awaiter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = False

    def __await__(self):
        while not self.ready:
            yield
```

And the caller code:

```
await awaiter
```

This works, but it requires boilerplate code. Is it necessary boilerplate or is there a special syntax to await on a predicate, such as:

```
await condition
```

which would yield until condition is false?

Answer (score 1):

At the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) package there is a builtin [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#condition) object that you can use.

> An asyncio condition primitive can be used by a task to wait for some event to happen and then get exclusive access to a shared resource.

How to use the condition (from the same source):

```
cond = asyncio.Condition()

# The preferred way to use a Condition is an async with statement
async with cond:
    await cond.wait()

# It can also be used as follow
await cond.acquire()
try:
    await cond.wait()
finally:
    cond.release()
```

A code example:

```
import asyncio

cond = asyncio.Condition()

async def func1():
    async with cond:
        print('It\'s look like I will need to wait')
        await cond.wait()
        print('Now it\'s my turn')

async def func2():
    async with cond:
        print('Notifying....')
        cond.notify()
        print('Let me finish first')

# Main function
async def main(loop):
    t1 = loop.create_task(func1())
    t2 = loop.create_task(func2())
    await asyncio.wait([t1, t2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    l.run_until_complete(main(l))
    l.close()
```

This will results with:

```
It's look like I will need to wait
Notifying....
Let me finish first
Now it's my turn
```

---

An alternative way is to use the [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event).

```
import asyncio

event = asyncio.Event()

async def func1():
    print('It\'s look like I will need to wait')
    await event.wait()
    print('Now it\'s my turn')


async def func2():
    print('Notifying....')
    event.set()
    print('Let me finish first')
```

It will have the same results as the `Condition` code example.